# Forcing language to not change

Tags: android

I have app in android studio and When i install APK and Language is English,

it show language of app like i want, but when phone language is different like Persian, it show other language in app and i don't want it...

how i can force app to use same English even language of phone changed?

my application is in Android studio and just one line have problem, mean there is a line words in application, and when i change language phone, it change to a different language same i don't want.

this is my main.xml (same line code

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diffText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dhuhar After one hour  10 min"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this one is not available in my string.xml, it mean it not translated, correct?

and cause "one hour 10min" is not stable, there is easy way i force it to use for all language same use for english?

Comment: do not provide translations in other languages then.. check the docs for more info https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html. You should only keep one strings.xml and in en folder

Comment: add both english and persian running screenshot too

Answer (score 1):

I set below code in oncreate and solved

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only english for all languages, dont set different language xml.. Just provide only default strings.xml.. app will show what ever text in strings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define your string in other language files (only write `<string name="yourstring" translatable="false">Your english string</string>`) then you will get your expected behavior.

That is because it takes the strings from `values/` if they are not available in the specific folder for the current language (e.g. `values-de/`)